# Error 1 Use of unassigned local variable 'Reports'

Tags: c#, global-variables, overloading

I cant get the reason why the first "Reports" isnt working

im not entriely sure what to do ive written similar code before and that works

```
Transfers Reports;

for (int i = 0; i < TransferList.Count; i++)
{
    Reports.PlayerName = TransferList[i].PlayerName;
    Reports.OldTeam = TransferList[i].OldTeam;
    Reports.NewTeam = TransferList[i].NewTeam;
    Reports.YearBought = TransferList[i].YearBought;
    Reports.YearSold = TransferList[i].YearSold;
    Reports.SellingPrice = TransferList[i].SellingPrice;
    Reports.WageGiven = TransferList[i].WageGiven;
    Reports.OriginalPrice = TransferList[i].OriginalPrice;
    Reports.OriginalWage = TransferList[i].OriginalWage;
    Reports.Height = TransferList[i].Height;
    Reports.Age = TransferList[i].Age;
    Reports.BirthDate = TransferList[i].BirthDate;
    Reports.Nationality = TransferList[i].Nationality;
    Reports.TypeofMove = TransfersList[i].TypeofMove;

    if (Reports.TypeofMove == "Transfer")
    {
        TransfersList.Add(Reports);
    }

    if (Reports.TypeofMove == "Free Transfer")
    {
        FreeTransfersList.Add(Reports);
    }

    if (Reports.TypeofMove == "Loan")
    {
        TransfersList.Add(Reports);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're getting *"Use of unassigned local variable 'Reports'"*, than that means that you are using `Reports` without first initializing it. In your code, you have just:

```
Transfers Reports;
```

This defines the variable, but it is not referencing any actual object, so calling `Reports.PlayerName` would fail. You need something like:

```
Transfers Reports = new Transfers();
```

The `Transfers` type may not have a parameter-less constructor, so in that case you need to create it differently (it is hard to say how, without knowing the details).

Also, by looking at your example, I would think that you should probably move the variable declaration (and initialization) inside the `for` loop, because you are creating a new report for every item in `TransferList`. However, you should not modify the collection that you are iterating over, so perhaps you first need to copy `TransferList`. (Are you sure you want to iterate over a collection and then add new items to it during the iteration?)

Comment: How do i intialized a list?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `Transfers Reports;` with `Transfers Reports = new Transfers();` (or whatever the constructor needs)